# Loss function error in pytorch-How should I use the loss function?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function

I wrote this code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as f
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

class dnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(dnn, self).__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(in_features=1, out_features=3)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=3)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=1)

    def forward(self, out):
        out = f.leaky_relu(self.l1(out))
        out = f.leaky_relu(self.l2(out))
        out = f.leaky_relu(self.l3(out))
        return out

model = dnn()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

for k in range(100):
    for i in range(30):
        outputs = model(torch.tensor([i]).type(torch.FloatTensor))
        loss = criterion(outputs, torch.tensor([math.cos(i)]).type(torch.FloatTensor))
        *print(loss)*
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        optimizer.step()
    print('{}%'.format(k))

x = []
y = []
p = []

for i in range(30):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(math.cos(i))
    p.append(str(model(torch.tensor([i]).type(torch.FloatTensor))).split('[')[1].split(']')[0])

plt.plot(x, p, 'g')
plt.plot(x, y, 'b')

plt.show()
```

However, the results predicted by this model were very strange.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs6Q2.png

So I tried a few more times and kept getting similar results.
While I was looking at various variables in the code to solve the problem, I found something strange.

*print(loss)*:

```
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
tensor(-0., grad_fn=<DivBackward1>)
```

The loss function has not changed.
How do I solve this?

Comment: your problem is related to loss function choice, cross_entropy is used for multi-class classification problems, whereas you are using it for a one-dimensional regression problem. As such, your loss is always zero because cross_entropy will be looking at how well aligned are your class estimations, but with just one class (one dimension), they are always perfectly aligned. Something like the MSEloss would make more sense (loss is related to the distance between target and predicted value)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just modified the code and could see that the loss function is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need loss function for task of regression, for example

```
criterion = nn.L1Loss()
```

nn.CrossEntropyLoss() expects targets as indexes of class or probabilities of class, you can change your network for binary classification task

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as f
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import random

class dnn(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(dnn, self).__init__()
        self.l1 = nn.Linear(in_features=1, out_features=3)
        self.l2 = nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=3)
        self.l3 = nn.Linear(in_features=3, out_features=2)

    def forward(self, out):
        out = f.leaky_relu(self.l1(out))
        out = f.leaky_relu(self.l2(out))
        out = f.leaky_relu(self.l3(out))
        
        return out

model = dnn()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.1)

for k in range(100):
    for i in range(30):
        # print(torch.tensor([i]))
        outputs = model(torch.tensor([i]).type(torch.FloatTensor))
        
        loss = criterion(outputs, torch.tensor([math.cos(i), 0]).type(torch.FloatTensor))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        optimizer.step()
    print('{}%'.format(k))

x = []
y = []
p = []

for i in range(30):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(math.cos(i))
    p.append(str(model(torch.tensor([i]).type(torch.FloatTensor))).split('[')[1].split(']')[0])

plt.plot(x, p, 'g')
plt.plot(x, y, 'b')

plt.show()
```